# How can you customize the navigation icon in google maps API android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps

Okay so I know there's a lot of ways you can customize pins for a Google maps app in Kotlin by doing something like that:

```
        val mMarker = mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions()
            .position(party)
            .title("SomeTitleOfSomeKind")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)))
```

However, I haven't found a way to actually modify the positioning icon (blue pointer) indicating the device location, but I know it should be possible to do it.

I'm talking about this guy here:

[image: This is the marker to be customized]

Anyone has any idea on how to do it?

Thanks!